# Facebook API: Raise HTTP Error(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to get a request from facebook with the API developer. It returns as an error :

raise HTTP Error(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTP Error: Bad Request

I'm new to the Facebook API and it looks obvious that I'm sending a bad request but I can't figure out what's wrong withit. How can I fix this problem?

```
    import urllib.request
    import json
    import datetime
    import csv
    import time
    import facebook


app_id = "172"
app_secret = "cefd3"

access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret
#Page ID 

page_id = 'cnn'


def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):

    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7"
    node = "/" + page_id
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token)
```

Comment: Check what the response body contains.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's User-agent's issue they are probably blocking the fact that it isn't coming from a browser. You probably need a valid User-Agent header or something.

Try using requests, this works:

```
import requests
headers = 
{
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print r
print r.headers
```